# Mysql docker container is not mounted

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've created mysql docker container using docker-compose. I built the container and created some tables in mysql. But, when i restarted my computer, i lost my data (tables and data) in mysql. I'am using a local folder in container as a volume. But i see that it's not mounted in virtual container.

My OS is Windows 10 Pro. I've tried to restart the Docker desktop and the containers, but it did not help. Here is the `.yml` that i'm running:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db_name'
      MYSQL_USER: 'db_user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'db_pass'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'db_root_pass'
    ports:
      - '3308:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-log:/var/log/mysql
      - ./dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
```

Comment: Are you running your docker-compose file from the same directory?

Comment: Could be a Permission Issue. Try running without Daemon (-d) . So you can see whats Happening.
At the same time try adding some data and see whether ./dbdata folder is updating or not

Comment: @NestorSokil yes sir

Comment: @ManujaJayawardana, sir i got the message from the logs: ` Aborted connection 2 to db: 'fin_expert' user: 'db_user' host: '172.19.0.1' (Got an error reading communication packets)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some permission problems with MySQL docker image. So instead of using MySQL, you can use MariaDB which has [no issues](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/69#issuecomment-269537249) with the docker volumes

In your docker-compose, you are mounting dbdata from the current directory which will not mount due to some permission problems of docker volumes with MySQL docker image. 
Mounting to a shared folder is not working so, Instead of using ./dbdata try to use /dbdata

Even I faced the same problem and I have changed MySQL to MariaDB and mounted my volumes to /dbdata and it worked for me. Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'movies'
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '123'
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1234'
    ports:
    # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
    # Where our data will be persisted
    volumes:
      - /dbdata :/var/lib/mysql
```

In your case, the database and tables which you have created are not persisted.
If you have the backup file of your tables then move that backup file to the /dbdata in your virtual machine and then you create database and load that backup file into your database

Comment: The problem is that i need to restore my data from the local volume.

Comment: I have modified my answer. There are some problems with mounting volumes. It is not mounting for shared folders